# Adding more backup GRUB entries

Tags: fedora, linux-kernel, grub

I'm using Fedora 24. Whenever I update the kernel, Fedora saves the two previous entries as backups, in case something goes wrong with the update.

I want to try to compile the kernel on my own (I want to enable ipv6 subtrees), and I would like the newly compiled kernel to be in a separate entry, not overwriting any of the fedora entries.

I tried to make five entries by setting `installonly_limit=5` in `/etc/dnf/dnf.conf`, and I upgraded the kernel, but on reboot I still only see 3 entries, not 5. (Actually there are 6, 3 Fedora, 1 fedora recovery(?) and 2 windows. But I would like 5 for Fedora.)

Do I need to change anything else? Will compiling a new kernel overwrite any previous entries or will it just add an entry?